# Importance sampling in R

Tags: r

I'm a beginner to statistics and currently learning Importance Sampling. I have searched through similar problems here but still can't get mine solved.

If I need to evaluate `E(x)` of a target distribution

```
f(x)=2 * x * exp(-x^2), x>0
```

By using Importance Sampling, I take a proposal distribution

```
g(x)=exp(-x)
```

Then

```
E(x)=integral(x* (f(x)/g(x)) * g(x) dx)
    =integral(exp(-x) * 4 * x^2 dx)
```

My R code was like this

```
x=rexp(1000)
w=4*x^2
y=exp(-w)
mean(y)
```

Am I doing it right? 
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I think you need theoretic advice first. This forum is for people who know that algorithmic steps are needed an.d it does not appear you are quite there yet

Answer (score 3):

It is simply the weighted sample mean.

Non weighted sample mean `mean(x)` gives you the expectation of proposal density; while weighted sample mean `mean(w * x)` gives the expectation of target density. But you are using a wrong weight. I think the correct one is `w <- 2 * x * exp(-x^2 + x)`.

If I were you, I would not compute weights myself. I would do

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rexp(1000)  ## samples from proposal density
f <- function(x) 2 * x *exp(-x^2)  ## target density
w <- f(x) / dexp(x)  ## importance weights

mean(x)  ## non-weighted sample mean
# [1] 1.029677

mean(w * x)  ## weighted sample mean
# [1] 0.9380861
```

In theory, the expectation of weights should be 1. But practically you only get close to 1:

```
mean(w)
[1] 1.036482
```

So, you might want the normalized version:

```
mean(w * x) / mean(w)
[1] 0.9050671
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to do something like this:

```
x<-rexp(n=1000,r=1)
fx<-function(x){
  return(x^2*exp(-(x^2)))
}
gx<-function(x){
  return(exp(-x))
}

Ex=mean(x*fx(x)/gx(x))
```

Comment: In this example, does choice of x function vary with the density function being used? If yes, how do we determine that? If fx and gx are different functions, how will we choose x function or a transformation of uniform function?